# How can I retrieve variables from parfor on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am trying to retrieve a variable I executed on a parfor (parallel for) on MATLAB but I can't. Heres my code:

```
clear all
clc    
matlabpool open 4

parfor i = 1:4
    a = 2^i;
end

matlabpool close
```

I would like to be able to recover the different values that were executed on the different workers. For example, I would like to access a(1) with a value of 2^1, a(2) with a value of 2^2, and so on. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple values when you are overwriting a single variable `a` , Try instead:

```
clear; clc;
matlabpool open 4

a = zeros(4,1); 
parfor i = 1:4
    a(i) = 2^i;
end

matlabpool close
```

and there are good examples of how to use `parfor` in matlab documentation of it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html).